# Lipschitz continuity, convexity, and estimate about $\frac{((u(t,x)-g(x))^+)^{1/k}}{\lambda}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

Consider the difference $$\frac{((u(t,x)-g(x))^+)^{1/k}}{\lambda} - \frac{((w(t,x)-g(x))^+)^{1/k}}{\lambda},$$

where $\lambda >0$ (small), $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $u,w$ are bounded and continuous functions on $[0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^N$, $g$ is a bounded and continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $(\cdot)^+$ is the positive part function.

**Questions:**

1. Is $\frac{((u(t,x)-g(x))^+)^{1/k}}{\lambda}$ lipschitz and convex?
2. Can we have an estimate like 
   $$\frac{((u(t,x)-g(x))^+)^{1/k}}{\lambda} - \frac{((w(t,x)-g(x))^+)^{1/k}}{\lambda} \le C||u(t,x)-w(t,x)||_{L^\infty}.$$
   If not, what kind of estimates can we have?
3. In points 1. and 2., do we have the same results if we consider  $(\cdot)^-$ instead of $(\cdot)^+$ (wher $(\cdot)^-$ is the negative part function)?

Comment: please correct your post where is $()^-$ in the difference?

Comment: @GuyFsone It is not in the difference. It appears only in question 3. I edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: $\lambda$ is just a constant? And in 1., Lipschitz and convex on what domain?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, $\lambda$ is a small constant (we may call it $\varepsilon$ to fix ideas). I meant on the space $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: This is weird. Why even have $\lambda?$ It cannot affect the conclusion in any way. Also in 1. you mean Lipschitz and convex on $\mathbb R^N$ for each $t\in [0,T]$? Really you should make this clear in the statement.